# case_when() in R returns a larger length vector than is expected

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Why does case when return a larger length vector when the evaluated condition only is length one?

This is using the dplyr::case_when().

Here is my example:

```
g <- list("something", c(1:10))

case_when( g[[1]] == "not something" ~ sum(g[[2]]), 
           g[[1]] == "something" ~ g[[2]][3], 
           TRUE ~ g[[2]]
)
```

I would've expected the result to be 3 instead of

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Edit: Reviewing the documentation for the function perhaps the above should return an error instead of running?

> **Value** 
> A vector of length 1 or n, matching the length of the logical input or
> output vectors, with the type (and attributes) of the first RHS.
> Inconsistent lengths or types will generate an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue comes from the last condition `TRUE ~ g[[2]]` that returns a vector. Other conditions returns a single value and that confuses `case_when`.

You can achieve what you want by unifying the output to the list.

```
case_when( g[[1]] == "not something" ~ list(sum(g[[2]])), 
       g[[1]] == "something" ~ list(g[[2]][3]), 
       TRUE ~ g[2]
)
```